# How to parse a Json String which I m getting as a response to get the data separated and stored in different variable?

Tags: json, windows-phone-7

{"OFFERS":[{"OFFER_ID":"490","OFFER_IMAGE":"http://www.discountbox.in/DiscountBoxUpload/19007012.JPG","OFFER":"Clearence Stock"},{"OFFER_ID":"488","OFFER_IMAGE":"http://www.discountbox.in/DiscountBoxUpload/36911135.JPG","OFFER":"Upto 20% Off"},{"OFFER_ID":"487","OFFER_IMAGE":"http://www.discountbox.in/DiscountBoxUpload/19373615.JPG","OFFER":"Upto 40% Off"},{"OFFER_ID":"486","OFFER_IMAGE":"http://www.discountbox.in/DiscountBoxUpload/16587130.JPG","OFFER":"Special Discount"},{"OFFER_ID":"485","OFFER_IMAGE":"http://www.discountbox.in/DiscountBoxUpload/56376547.JPG","OFFER":"Upto 10% Off"},{"OFFER_ID":"484","OFFER_IMAGE":"http://www.discountbox.in/DiscountBoxUpload/20302235.JPG","OFFER":"Free Eye Testing"},{"OFFER_ID":"483","OFFER_IMAGE":"http://www.discountbox.in/DiscountBoxUpload/14323344.JPG","OFFER":"Best Special Ra"},{"OFFER_ID":"482","OFFER_IMAGE":"http://www.discountbox.in/DiscountBoxUpload/19790443.JPG","OFFER":"Flat 10% Off"},{"OFFER_ID":"481","OFFER_IMAGE":"http://www.discountbox.in/DiscountBoxUpload/13783976.JPG","OFFER":"Flat 20% Off "},{"OFFER_ID":"480","OFFER_IMAGE":"http://www.discountbox.in/DiscountBoxUpload/77105375.jpg","OFFER":"Flat 20% Off"},{"OFFER_ID":"479","OFFER_IMAGE":"http://www.discountbox.in/DiscountBoxUpload/91484956.jpg","OFFER":"Upto 50% Off"},{"OFFER_ID":"478","OFFER_IMAGE":"http://www.discountbox.in/DiscountBoxUpload/25738727.jpg","OFFER":"Bumper Dhamaka"}]}

I need to get the data as OfferID, Image and Offer stored in different variables.
Is there any way to do it in Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone.Please Help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com)?

Comment: I dont know how to use it in my applicaton. :(
Can u please help me about how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://json2csharp.com/ to create a class to deserialize to.

```
public class OFFER
{
    public string OFFER_ID { get; set; }
    public string OFFER_IMAGE { get; set; }
    public string OFFER { get; set; }
}

public class OfferResponse
{
    public List<OFFER> OFFERS { get; set; }
}
```

Then, using [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx):

```
var deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OfferResponse>(json);
```

Comment: I dont know how to use the Json.net...I m new to this thing...can you please help me?

Comment: That single line of code will deserialize the json you listed.

Comment: Ok. Now I got it. Really appreciate your help. Do you know how to then display this data on the phone?...

Comment: There are several ways,try a ListBox.